# Java API - Pentaho - PDI - The transformation path ... is invalid, and will not run successfully

Tags: java, pentaho, transformation, pdi

I'm using java api for de transformations.

When I running local (eclipse/windows), the transformation works perfectly! But I will run in linux, the transformation doens't works and return the problem:

"The transformation path file:/opt/platform/erpx-fnd-importacao-develop-SNAPSHOT/erpx-fnd-importacao-develop-SNAPSHOT-assembled-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/fnd_pessoa.ktr **is invalid, and will not run successfully".**

My software is running with docker and linux Ubuntu.

My code:

```
try {
    KettleEnvironment.init();
    Trans transformation = new Trans(new 
    TransMeta(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("fnd_pessoa").getFile()));
    transformation.execute(null);
    transformation.waitUntilFinished();
    if (transformacao.getErrors() > 0) {
      LOGGER.error("Ocorreram erros durante a importação");
   }
} catch (KettleException e) {
  throw new KettleExceptions("Problemas ao inicializar PDI - Kettle ", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem similar to yours. See the figure below for specific errors. My solution is due to The ktr file and the PDI actual installation folder are not in the same directory, so the command line adds the - norep parameter. The correct script: `sh /usr/local/data-integration(the PDI installation directory)/pan.sh -norep -file=/home/etl/ktr/xxx.ktr(the ktr actual directory)[enter image description here][1]`